# Displaying the output of Process.Start

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a Process.Start command that I would like to see the output of, but the new window is opening and closing too quickly for me to see anything. Here is the code I have so far that I'm working with:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VS110COMNTOOLS") & "..\Ide\MSTEST.EXE", "/Testsettings: """ & rwSettings & "" & " /Testcontainer: """ & rwContainer & "" & " /Resultsfile: """ & rwResults & "")
```

Unfortunately as I try to debug this if I allow this to run it flashes up the window but doesn't let me see what the error is, or if it's running successfully at all. I'm using VS2012 so I might just not be looking at the right view when I'm debugging.

Comment: Run cmd.exe instead.  Make the argument "/c prog.exe args && pause" or "/k prog.exe args".

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code taen out of the middle of some logic, so it is not standalone. You can use ProcessStartInfo() and Process() to have more control:

```
        Dim start_info As New ProcessStartInfo("sqlcmd", cmd)
        start_info.UseShellExecute = False
        start_info.CreateNoWindow = True
        start_info.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        start_info.RedirectStandardError = True

        ' Make the process and set its start information.
        Dim proc As New Process()
        proc.StartInfo = start_info

        Dim dt As Date = Now()

        ' Start the process.
        proc.Start()

         ' Attach to stdout and stderr.
        Dim std_out As StreamReader = proc.StandardOutput() ' will not continue until process stops
        Dim std_err As StreamReader = proc.StandardError()

        ' Retrive the results.
        Dim sOut As String = std_out.ReadToEnd()
        Dim sErr As String = std_err.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: Hans answer is better if you just want to view the results on the screen.